# Return value from wxPython Frame

Tags: python, wxpython

Could someone show me how I could return a value from a wxPython Frame? When the use clicks close, I popup a message dialog asking him a question. I would like to return the return code of this message dialog to my calling function.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear for me what you mean. Could you explain it better or give some code?. Is the Dialog opened when you close the Frame?. Dialogs and Frames are different classes in wxPython. It is not clear from the title and text whether you actually refer to a Frame or a Dialog

Comment: I assume the OP wants the text that the user inputs to the pop-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the wxFrame has events that process via the app.MainLoop() functionality, the only way to get at the return value of a wx.Frame() is via catching an event.

The standard practice of handling events is typically from within the class which derives from wx.Window itself (e.g., Frame, Panel, etc.).  Since you want code exterior to the wx.Frame to receive information that was gathered upon processing the OnClose() event, then the best way to do that is to register an event handler for your frame.

The documentation for wx.Window::PushEventHandler is probably the best resource and even the [wxpython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/PushEventHandler) has a great article on how to do this.  Within the article, they register a custom handler which is an instance of "MouseDownTracker."  Rather than instantiating within the PushEventHandler call, you'd want to instantiate it prior to the call so that you can retain a handle to the EventHandler derived class.  That way, you can check on your derived EventHandler class-variables after the Frame has been destroyed, or even allow that derived class to do special things for you.

Here is an adaptation of that code from the wx python wiki (admittedly a little convoluted due to the requirement of handling the results of a custom event with a "calling" function):

```py
import sys
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent
    
(MyCustomEvent, EVT_CUSTOM) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
    
class CustomEventTracker(wx.EvtHandler):
    def __init__(self, log, processingCodeFunctionHandle):
        wx.EvtHandler.__init__(self)
        self.processingCodeFunctionHandle = processingCodeFunctionHandle
        self.log = log
        EVT_CUSTOM(self, self.MyCustomEventHandler)
    
    def MyCustomEventHandler(self, evt):
        self.log.write(evt.resultOfDialog + '\n')
        self.processingCodeFunctionHandle(evt.resultOfDialog)
        evt.Skip()
    
class MyPanel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.log = log
    
    def OnResults(self, resultData):
        self.log.write("Result data gathered: %s" % resultData)
    
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=-1, title="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos, size, style)
        self.panel = panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN | wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add((25, 25))
    
        row = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row.Add((25,1))
        m_close = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Close")
        m_close.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
        row.Add(m_close, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(row)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    
    def OnClose(self, evt):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Do you really want to close this frame?", "Confirm Exit", wx.OK | wx.CANCEL | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            event = MyCustomEvent(resultOfDialog="User Clicked CANCEL")
            self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(event)
        else: # result == wx.ID_OK
            event = MyCustomEvent(resultOfDialog="User Clicked OK")
            self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(event)
        self.Destroy()
    
app = wx.App(False)
f2 = wx.Frame(None, title="Frame 1 (for feedback)", size=(400, 350))
p2 = MyPanel2(f2, sys.stdout)
f2.Show()
eventTrackerHandle = CustomEventTracker(sys.stdout, p2.OnResults)
f1 = MyFrame(None, title="PushEventHandler Tester (deals with on close event)", size=(400, 350))
f1.PushEventHandler(eventTrackerHandle)
f1.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3):

A few years late for the initial question, but when looking for the answer to this question myself, I stumbled upon a built-in method of getting a return value from a modal without messing with any custom event funniness. Figured I'd post here in case anyone else needs it.

It's simply this guy right here:

> **wxDialog::EndModal void EndModal(***int retCode***)**
>
> *Ends a modal dialog, passing a value to be returned from the*
>   *wxDialog::ShowModal invocation.*

Using the above, you can return whatever you want from the Dialog.

An example usage would be subclassing a `wx.Dialog`, and then placing the `EndModal` function in the button handlers.

```
class ProjectSettingsDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, "Project Settings", size=(600,400))

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) #main sized
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1) 

        msg = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label="This is a sample message")
        sizer.Add(msg, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALL, 15)


        horizontal_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        okButton = wx.Button(self, -1, 'OK')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK, okButton)

        cancelBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Cancel")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, cancelBtn)

        horizontal_sizer.Add(okButton, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        horizontal_sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
        horizontal_sizer.Add(cancelBtn, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

        sizer.Add(horizontal_sizer, 0)

        sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
            self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnOK(self, event):
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK) #returns numeric code to caller
        self.Destroy()


    def OnCancel(self, event):
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL) #returns numeric code to caller
        self.Destroy()
```

*(Note: I just banged this code out quickly; didn't test the sizers)*

As you can see, all you need to do is call the `EndModal` from a button event to return a value to whatever spawned the dialog.

Comment: Your answer speaks to a wxDialog whereas the question speaks to a wxFrame.  *Obviously* for retrieving a value from a popup, a wxDialog is much preferred over a frame.  However, you did not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result of clicking the OK, CANCEL buttons from the Dialog ShowModal method.
Given dialog is an instance of one of the wxPython Dialog classes:

```
result = dialog.ShowModal()
if result == wx.ID_OK:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "Cancel"
dialog.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, to have a graphical "picker" that I could run from within a console app. Here's how I did it.

```
# Fruit.py

import wx

class Picker (wx.App):
    def __init__ (self, title, parent=None, size=(400,300)):
        wx.App.__init__(self, False)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(parent, title=title, size=size)

        self.apple_button = wx.Button(self.frame, -1, "Apple", (0,0))
        self.apple_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.apple_button_click)

        self.orange_button = wx.Button(self.frame, -1, "Orange", (0,100))
        self.orange_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.orange_button_click)

        self.fruit = None
        self.frame.Show(True)

    def apple_button_click (self, event):
        self.fruit = 'apple'
        self.frame.Destroy()

    def orange_button_click (self, event):
        self.fruit = 'orange'
        self.frame.Destroy()

    def pick (self):
        self.MainLoop()
        return self.fruit
```

Then from a console app, I would run this code.

```
# Usage.py

import Fruit

picker = Fruit.Picker('Pick a Fruit')
fruit = picker.pick()
print 'User picked %s' % fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

user1594322's answer works but it requires you to put all of your controls in your wx.App, instead of wx.Frame. This will make recycling the code harder.

My solution involves define a "PassBack" variable when defining your **init** function. (similar to "parent" variable, but it is normally used already when initiating a wx.Frame)

From my code:

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None, size=(500,700)):
        wx.App.__init__(self, False)
        self.frame = MyFrame(parent, -1, passBack=self) #Pass this app in
        self.outputFromFrame = "" #The output from my frame


    def getOutput(self):
        self.frame.Show()
        self.MainLoop()
        return self.outputFromFrame
```

and for the frame class:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, passBack, title="My Frame"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, size=(500, 700))
        self.passBack = passBack #this will be used to pass back variables/objects
```

and somewhere during the execution of MyFrame

```
self.passBack.outputFromFrame = "Hello"
```

so all in all, to get a string from an application

```
app = MyApp()
val = app.getOutput()
#Proceed to do something with val
```

Comment: It also has the advantage of being able to pass multiple variables/objects back during execution. Just make sure you run sanity checks before using any values (such as checking for len(val) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer on comp.lang.python: [Linkie](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/32a3fe6b25288bc7)

Comment: that link goes to a book on amazon about assembly language.

Comment: What? My clipboard betrayed me. Imagine it was bestiality, instead. Argh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a wxFrame can return a value since it is not modal.  If you don't need to use a wxFrame, then a modal dialog could work for you.  If you really need a frame, I'd consider using a custom event.

It would go something like this:
(1) User clicks to close the wxFrame
(2) You override OnClose (or something like that) to pop up a dialog to ask the user a question
(3) Create and post the custom event
(4) Close the wxFrame
(5) Some other code processes your custom event

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had the same problem as you. Instead of making that popup a frame, I made it a dialog instead. I made a custom dialog by inheriting a wx.dialog instead of a wx.frame. Then you can utilize the code that joaquin posted above. You check the return value of the dialog to see what was entered. This can be done by storing the value of the textctrl when the user clicks ok into a local variable. Then before it's destroyed, you get that value somehow.

The custom dialog section of this site helped me out greatly.
http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/